# Do responses get cached even if there is no cache-control header?

Tags: google-chrome, http, caching, cache-control

I'm trying to understand why this resource is being cached even though there is no `cache-control` header returned in the response.
[image]

How is it possible that this resource is being cached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is addressed in [Section 4.2.2 of RFC 7234](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234#section-4.2.2):

> Since origin servers do not always provide explicit expiration times,
> a cache MAY assign a heuristic expiration time when an explicit time
> is not specified, employing algorithms that use other header field
> values (such as the `Last-Modified` time) to estimate a plausible
> expiration time.

And, indeed, browsers do this.

Comment: So to ensure a resource is not cached, it must return `Cache-Control: no-store`?

Comment: @DavidKlempfner: That's right.